# Error when deleting allocated memory in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am new to C++ and am trying to understand the proper way to deallocated array memory. I am getting the following error when try to delete an allocated pointer array:
"pointer being freed was not allocated."

My pointer is defined as:

```
T * al ;
al = new T[top] ;
```

While my destructor for the class where the pointer `al` is defined in is:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < current ; i++ )
        delete( al+i ) ;
    delete [] al ;
```

The destructor for the `class T` is:

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ )
        delete( p+1 ) ;
delete [] p ;
```

Where `p` is defined as:

```
char *p ;
length = strlen( str ) ;
p = new char[length] ;
strcpy( p, str ) ;
```

How to properly allocate memory and/ or how to fix this?

Comment: Use `std::string` and `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `delete []`, not the loop in addition.  `delete []` will delete each element of the array.

Also, your loop in the class `T` destructor is trying to delete `p+1` instead of `p+i`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, using sully the delete [] in both destructors still gives me the same error.  Or did you mean that I should only use it in the one?

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, you should `delete` like so:

```
int *a = new int; // One allocated
delete a;         // So delete one

int *b = new int[50]; // 50 allocated
delete[] b;           // Just use delete[], don't delete every one

int **c = new int*[50]; // 50 pointers to ints
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    c[i] = new int;     // each c[i] points to a pointer to a new int

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    delete c[i];
delete[] c;
```

Use `delete` when you use `new`, `delete[]` when you use `new[]`.

---

It's actually wrong to do the following:

```
int *a = new int[50];

// do stuff...

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
   delete &a[i]; // equivalent to delete (a + i);
delete[] a;
```

You only do a `delete[] a`, never the `delete (a + i)`.